# UITableViewHeaderFooterView.detailTextLabel is not displayed

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview

I've got a problem with `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class usage.
In my app I want to use both `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties to display some text, but `detailTextLabel` is not displayed. As far as I've understood Apple's documentation, `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties should work similar to well-known `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties of `UITableViewCell` class.
Here is my sample class code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblMain;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tblMain;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tblMain.delegate = self;
    tblMain.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"cell is not interesting";
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}// Default is 1 if not implemented


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"header";
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (!header) {
        header = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
    header.textLabel.text = @"t";
    header.detailTextLabel.text = @"dtext";
    return header;
}

@end
```

If one compile this code, it will show a table with three sections and one row in each section. I thought I'll get sections with 't' on the left side and 'dtext' on the right side, but 'dtext' is missed.
Where is error in my code? What is to be done to view detailTextLabel? A link to a working example of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` `detailTextLabel` property would also be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you increase the height of the headers and see if it is just placed out of view. You will probably need to override 
`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section`

Comment: `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section` is overriden, it is the last method in my class in my post. If you mean `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section ` - I'd try this, enlarging height up to 50.0  -it does not help.

Comment: Just for try, can you make reuseIdentifier = nil; in - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section. May be reusability problem. (i am just guessing)

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the header for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, you'll find that `detailTextLabel` only works for `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. I'm guessing you're using `UITableViewStylePlain`.

From `UITableViewHeaderFooterView.h`:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel* detailTextLabel; // only supported for headers in grouped style
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in the framework or the documentation. The `detailTextLabel` is present, but it always has a zero frame so it is always invisible. Therefore it is always useless.

The simplest solution is not to use the built-in labels; put your own subviews into the `contentView`. (Do not attempt to mix and match your own custom subviews with the built-in labels.)